# Advice on creating SQL joins

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I'm having a tough time getting a query to yield the rows I need, either giving too few or too many duplicates.

Ultimately, what I want is a query that yields all non-duplicate resources where cid > 0.

I've researched other answers but most just provide a query that works. I'm hopeful that answers will help me and others *understand* query building better. THANKS!

TL;DR version follows...

The following query yields duplicates:

```
SELECT DISTINCTROW r.rid, r.rname, c.cid, c.spanclass, c.cname, u.name, r.time
FROM rmn_resources as r, rmn_users as u, rmn_conditions as c
WHERE c.cid=r.cid
```

Here is my attempt at showing the data:

```
|r.rid  |r.rname        |c.cid  |c.spanclass        |c.cname        |u.name |r.time
|1      |'Keyfob #1'    |0      |NULL               |'Created'      |User B |'0000-00-00 00:00:00'
|1      |'Keyfob #1'    |0      |NULL               |'Created'      |User A |'0000-00-00 00:00:00'
|2      |'Keyfob #2'    |1      |'label-success'    |'Available'    |User B |'2013-04-13 02:17:07'
|2      |'Keyfob #2'    |1      |'label-success'    |'Available'    |User A |'2013-04-13 02:17:07'
|3      |'Keyfob #3'    |2      |'label-important'  |'Checked out'  |User B |'2013-04-13 18:11:17'
|3      |'Keyfob #3'    |2      |'label-important'  |'Checked out'  |User A |'2013-04-13 18:11:17'
|5      |'Spork'        |1      |'label-success'    |'Available'    |User B |'2013-04-14 02:29:39'
|5      |'Spork'        |1      |'label-success'    |'Available'    |User A |'2013-04-14 02:29:39'
```

I have a variation that reduces the duplicates, but still has two records where I want only one:

```
SELECT DISTINCTROW r.rid, r.rname, c.cid, c.spanclass, c.cname, u.name, r.time
FROM rmn_resources as r, rmn_users as u, rmn_conditions as c
WHERE c.cid=r.cid AND (u.uid=r.uid OR (r.uid=0 AND r.cid>0))
```

And another that yields no duplicates but doesn't display my beloved Spork.

```
SELECT DISTINCTROW r.rid, r.rname, c.cid, c.spanclass, c.cname, u.name, r.time
FROM rmn_resources as r, rmn_users as u, rmn_conditions as c
WHERE c.cid=r.cid AND u.uid=r.uid
```

(Honestly, I was shooting in the dark here, trying to wrangle the query.)

Here are the basic tables in SQL form (apologies no TL;DR version)

Table: rmn_resources

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `rmn_resources` (
  `rid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `rname` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `oid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'owner uid in users',
  `cid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'cid: condition id in conditions',
  `time` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP COMMENT 'NULL or last changed time',
  `uid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'user uid from users',
  PRIMARY KEY (`rid`) ) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=6 ;

INSERT INTO `rmn_resources` (`rid`, `rname`, `oid`, `cid`, `time`, `uid`) VALUES
(1, 'Keyfob #1', 0, 0, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 0),
(2, 'Keyfob #2', 0, 1, '2013-04-13 08:17:07', 1),
(3, 'Keyfob #3', 0, 2, '2013-04-14 00:11:17', 2),
(5, 'Spork', 1, 1, '2013-04-14 08:29:39', 0);
```

Table: rmn_users

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `rmn_users` (
  `uid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`uid`),
  UNIQUE KEY `email` (`email`),
  KEY `name` (`name`) ) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;

INSERT INTO `rmn_users` (`uid`, `name`, `email`) VALUES
(1, 'User A', 'usera@users.com'),
(2, 'User B', 'userb@users.com');
```

Table: rmn_conditions

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `rmn_conditions` (
  `cid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `cname` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `spanclass` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`cid`) ) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=4 ;

INSERT INTO `rmn_conditions` (`cid`, `cname`, `spanclass`) VALUES
(0, 'Created', NULL),
(1, 'Available', 'label-success'),
(2, 'Checked out', 'label-important');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should start using explicit joins, your problem with duplicates is because you were cross joining. The last query is okay but it doesn't display spork because you don't have a matching user for it. You can use `LEFT JOIN` though like this:

```
SELECT r.rid, r.rname, c.cid, c.spanclass, c.cname, u.name, r.time
FROM rmn_resources AS r
LEFT JOIN rmn_users AS u
  ON u.uid=r.uid
LEFT JOIN rmn_conditions AS c
  ON c.cid=r.cid;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!8/4d5de/1

Comment: Eureka! I had tried a similar LEFT JOIN query before on conditions but not users. It led to some missing columns in the clause so I gave up that avenue of thinking. This got me close enough, and adding the WHERE (r.cid > 0) to the end of the query nails. it. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

You might want to read through [Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins) to get a better understanding of joins if you haven't already.

When table contains millions of rows, it gives you a huge advantage, memory and time wise, when you use specific joins when compared to the join you are currently using.

Hope it helps.

[image]